# Troubleshooting Regular Expressions in MediaWiki Extension Not Working

Tags: php, regex, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

The regex feature of the onParserBeforePreprocess function doesn't work in the extension I'm building, and I don't know why.

Let me elaborate on the issue with the onParserBeforePreprocess function not working.

extension.json:

```
{
    "name": "EnhanceMarkup",
    "description": "Provides enhanced markup functionalities",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": [
        "Jeong Gaon"
    ],
    "url": "https://www.gaon.xyz/mw_extensions",
    "type": "other",
    "license-name": "Apache-2.0",
    "AutoloadClasses": {
        "EnhanceMarkupHooks": "includes/EnhanceMarkupHooks.php"
    },
    "ResourceModules": {
        "ext.EnhanceMarkup.styles": {
            "styles": "resources/ext.EnhanceMarkup.styles.css",
            "localBasePath": "",
            "remoteExtPath": "EnhanceMarkup"
        },
        "ext.EnhanceMarkup.scripts": {
            "scripts": ["resources/ext.EnhanceMarkup.scripts.js", "resources/lib/math.js"],
            "localBasePath": "",
            "remoteExtPath": "EnhanceMarkup"
        }
    },
    "Hooks": {
        "InternalParseBeforeLinks": "EnhanceMarkupHooks::onInternalParseBeforeLinks",
        "ParserFirstCallInit": "EnhanceMarkupHooks::onParserFirstCallInit",
        "BeforePageDisplay": "EnhanceMarkupHooks::onBeforePageDisplay"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

includes/EnhanceMarkupHooks.php:

```
<?php
class EnhanceMarkupHooks
{
    public static function onBeforePageDisplay(OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin)
    {
        $out->addModules("ext.EnhanceMarkup.styles");
        $out->addModules("ext.EnhanceMarkup.scripts");
        return true;
    }

    public static function onParserFirstCallInit(Parser $parser)
    {
        // Register each of your custom parser functions with the parser
        $parser->setHook("random", [self::class, "randomRender"]);


        return true;
    }

    public static function onInternalParseBeforeLinks(Parser &$parser, &$text)
    {
        // - * 4+ == <hr>
        // Replace sequences of 3-9 '*', '-', or '_' with a horizontal rule
        $text = preg_replace('/^([-]{3,9})$/m', "<hr>", $text);

        // [pagecount] show all count of page
        // Replace [pagecount] with the total number of pages
        $text = preg_replace_callback(
            "/\[pagecount\]/",
            function ($matches) use ($parser) {
                $dbr = wfGetDB(DB_REPLICA);
                $count = $dbr->selectRowCount("page");
                return $count;
            },
            $text
        );

        // Replace [*A text] with <ref group="A">text</ref>
        $text = preg_replace(
            "/\[\*\s+([^ ]+)\s+(.*?)\]/",
            '<ref group="$1">$2</ref>',
            $text
        );

        // Replace [*A] with <ref group="A" />
        $text = preg_replace(
            "/\[\*\s+([^ ]+)\s*\]/",
            '<ref group="$1" />',
            $text
        );

        // Replace [* text] with <ref>text</ref>
        $text = preg_replace("/\[\*\s+(.*?)\]/", '<ref>$1</ref>', $text);

        // Replace [include text] with {{text}}
        $text = preg_replace("/\[\include\s+(.*?)\]/", '{{$1}}', $text);

        // Replace [br] with <br>
        $text = str_replace("[br]", "<br>", $text);

        // Font Size up {{{+1 (content) }}} - Range: 1~5
        $text = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{\{\+([1-5])\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}\}/s', function($matches) {
            return '<span style="font-size:'.(1 + $matches[1]).'em;">'.$matches[2].'</span>';
        }, $text);
        
        // Font Size down {{{-1 (content) }}} - Range: 1~5
        $text = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{\{-([1-5])\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}\}/s', function($matches) {
            return '<span style="font-size:'.(1 - $matches[1]/10).'em;">'.$matches[2].'</span>';
        }, $text);

        return true;
    }

    // Random
    // <random range="50">True|False</random>
    public static function randomRender(
        $input,
        array $args,
        Parser $parser,
        PPFrame $frame
    ) {
        // Disable caching
        $parser->getOutput()->updateCacheExpiry(0);

        // Parse the input
        $parts = explode("|", $input);

        // Get the range from args
        $range = isset($args["range"]) ? $args["range"] : 2; // default to 2

        // Generate a random number within the range
        $randomNumber = mt_rand(1, $range);

        // Choose the output based on the random number
        if ($randomNumber <= $range / 2) {
            // If the random number is in the first half of the range, return the first part
            return $parts[0];
        } else {
            // Otherwise, return the second part if it exists, or the first part if it doesn't
            return isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : $parts[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the code, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly wrong with it - if it's supposed to work, typing something like [* texts] within the wiki should generate a footnote called texts, but for some reason it's outputting literally.

For example, if you type 'hello[br]world', you should see world under hello, but nothing.

My MediaWiki site address is https://www.gaonwiki.com

Let me know if you need any more information. I'll provide it. Thank you.

Comment: Just looking at the few regexes, it seems to have some mistakes, typically for the `<hr>` generation, I would use `/^([*-]{3,9}\h*)$/m` as your comment says that you allow `***` or `---` and perhaps accepting spaces after could be a good point too. See playground here: https://regex101.com/r/cBV0ER/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** To match your references described by `[*A Text]`, I would correct
the pattern like this:

`/\[\*(?<group>\w+)\s+(?<text>[^\]]+)\]/`

The idea is to use named capturing groups with
`(?<group_name>...pattern...)`
and also to be a bit more precise with `\w+` to match word characters,
then `\s+` for one or several spaces and then any char which isn't the
closing bracket with `[^\]]+`.

The replacement becomes `<ref group="$group">$text</ref>`

Here are some tests of it: https://regex101.com/r/vueNcM/2

**B)** Step 2, to match only `[*A]`, I would use
`/\[\*(?<group>\w+)\]/` and replace it with `<ref group="$group" />`

Here are the tests too: https://regex101.com/r/gYFOzO/2

**C)** Step 3, to replace `[* text]` with `<ref>text</ref>`, I would
use first use `/\[\*\s+(?<text>[^\]]+)\]/` and replace it by
`<ref>$text</ref>`.

Tests available here: https://regex101.com/r/aYTOH9/1

But if you want to allow escaped bracket in the text (in case
the user needs to have some brackets in the text, then use
`/\[\*\s+(?<text>(?:\\\]|[^\]])+)\]/`

Tests: https://regex101.com/r/aYTOH9/2

For this situation, you'll have to do a *preg_replace_callback()*
instead of a simple *preg_replace()* because we have to unescape
the brackets:

```php
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[\*\s+(?<text>(?:\\\\\]|[^\]])+)\]/',
    function ($matches) {
        return '<ref>' .
            preg_replace('/\\\\([\[\]])/', '$1', $matches['text']) .
            '</ref>';
    },
    $text
);
```

Test the PHP here: https://onlinephp.io/c/2b5249

#### Security concerns when creating filters

What happens if the user inputs this?

```
Shit happens with [* <script>alert('I got you')</script>]
```

Will there be another filter to avoid XSS attacks?

If it's not safely escaped, then replace all your *preg_replace()*
calls by a *preg_replace_callback()* like in example C) above and
do the sanitizing operations on the captured values:

```php
// Replace [* Some text] by <ref>Some text</ref>
// Also handle escaped brackets in text, such as [* An \[important\] reference]
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    // In the pattern, \ should be doubled, but only for known PHP escaped
    // sequences, such as \t, \n, \a, or \\. This makes the pattern below not
    // very readable :-( In JavaSript it would be simple like this:
    // /\[\*\s+(?<text>(?:\\\]|[^\]])+)\]/
    '/\[\*\s+(?<text>(?:\\\\\]|[^\]])+)\]/',
    function ($matches) {
        // 1) Unescape "\[" or "\]" by "[" and respectively "]".
        // 2) As we are creating HTML, the text should be sanitized as it may
        // contain some stuff like <strong>Bold</strong> or worse some JavaScript
        // <script>alert('XSS attack')</script>.
        return '<ref>' .
            htmlspecialchars(
                preg_replace('/\\\\([\[\]])/', '$1', $matches['text'])
            ) .
            '</ref>';
    },
    $text
);
```

PHP code in action here: https://onlinephp.io/c/8a7f8